# Search data from two table with joins how to handler null values

Tags: mysql

I have write a search query that will joining two different table. i have putted left join on both. Now first table contains 60records while based on that second table has only 30. Now i wanted if i search query should return all 60records. right now it is returning 30.
query same.

> select A.*,B.* from A left join B on A.Id=B.AId where
>   A.name=IfNull('tst',A.name) AND B.class=IFNull('c',B.class).

Please guide me, Thanks.

Comment: see after 30 records my table B has no values that match with A..infact table B has only 30 records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wise to remember that JOIN operations (all kinds of JOIN operations, LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, OUTER) have the purpose of creating a new, virtual, table that is assembled from the tables joined together.

What is this JOINed virtual table supposed to have in it?  In your case, what is the meaning of your column A.ID, and your column B.AID?

1. Are there rows in your A table with A.ID column values which occur no times in B.AID?
2. Are there rows in your B table with B.AID column values which occur no times in A.ID?

If the answer to question 1 is Yes and question 2 is No, then a LEFT JOIN will give you want you want.  But simplify your query.  Try this.

```
 SELECT A.*, B.*
   FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
```

If you happen to want only the rows from A where there is no corresponding row from B, try this.

```
 SELECT A.*
   FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
   WHERE B.AID IS NULL
```

If the answer to both questions is Yes, then you *may* want this:

```
 SELECT A.*, B.*
   FROM A
   OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
```

But you should think this through very carefully.

Comment: yes my problem has been solved. i wrote B.Name=ifnull('Test',B.Name) and value of B.Name that i am passing was null and table value is also null.so it should match but this condition was failing. and when I wrote B.Name is null it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Logic i hope it will work for you.....

```
select A.*,B.* from A left join B on A.Id=B.AId where B.Id != ''
```